# How should my service respond the Azure load balancer probe?

Tags: c#, azure, tcp, load-balancing

I have a Windows service running on port 25 handling SMTP traffic.

I can see from my log files that the Azure load balancer probe is making requests every 15 seconds to port 25.

The connection made by the probe remains open for 15 seconds, then is terminated by the remote host (probably so it can send the next probe, which would happen at this time).

How should the probe be handled so that it doesn't keep the connection open for 15 seconds?

Comment: I'd guess this is because of connection keep-alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long and short of this (on the current version) is that you can't tell that the connection is from the load balancer because it doesn't identify itself in any way.

I WireSharked it and there was nothing that would identify the connection - other than if you wanted to attempt to maintain the IP address or range of the load balancer so you could identify it by this.

Comment: Azure Load Balancer identifies itself for HTTP probes. Sample HTTP request:
GET / HTTP/1.1 Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent: Load Balancer Agent X-MS-LB-Host: 1.2.3.4:8080 X-MS-LB-MonitorStatus: Down Host: 1.2.3.4:8080

Comment: SMTP runs on TCP not HTTP.

Comment: The load balancer can be identified on TCP probes by it's IP address: 168.63.129.16

Comment: @MarkLauter that would make a great answer.